# Populate HTML select Tag with first input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Filling **every inputs** of a **working hours form** can be quite tedious.

Is there a way to populate every inputs from a form with the first entered value?

In the case of this Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/az8ujh1e/1/, a first input on any of the **opend** date would populate the other ones (that could still be modified one by one)
and a first input on the **closed** dates would do the same on all the closing dates.

Code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-sm-6">Opend</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">Closed</div>

<form role="form" action="#" method="POST"> 

      <div class="col-sm-6" id="timeopen1">
      <select  name="timeopen1" class='selectpicker' >
      <option value="00:00">00:00</option>
      <option value="01:00">01:00</option>
      <option value="02:00">02:00</option>
      <option value="03:00">03:00</option>
      <option value="04:00">04:00</option>
      <option value="04:00">05:00</option>
      <option value="04:00">06:00</option>
      </select>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-6" id="timeclosed1">
      <select  name="timeclosed1" class='selectpicker' >
      <option value="00:00">00:00</option>
      <option value="01:00">01:00</option>
      <option value="02:00">02:00</option>
      <option value="03:00">03:00</option>
      <option value="04:00">04:00</option>
      <option value="04:00">05:00</option>
      <option value="04:00">06:00</option>
      </select>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-6" id="timeopen2">
      <select  name="timeopen2" class='selectpicker' >
      <option value="00:00">00:00</option>
      <option value="01:00">01:00</option>
      <option value="02:00">02:00</option>
      <option value="03:00">03:00</option>
      <option value="04:00">04:00</option>
      <option value="04:00">05:00</option>
      <option value="04:00">06:00</option>
      </select>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-6" id="timeclosed2">
      <select  name="timeclosed2" class='selectpicker' >
      <option value="00:00">00:00</option>
      <option value="01:00">01:00</option>
      <option value="02:00">02:00</option>
      <option value="03:00">03:00</option>
      <option value="04:00">04:00</option>
      <option value="04:00">05:00</option>
      <option value="04:00">06:00</option>
      </select>
      </div>
      
      
      <div class="col-sm-6" id="timeopen3">
      <select  name="timeopen3" class='selectpicker' >
      <option value="00:00">00:00</option>
      <option value="01:00">01:00</option>
      <option value="02:00">02:00</option>
      <option value="03:00">03:00</option>
      <option value="04:00">04:00</option>
      <option value="04:00">05:00</option>
      <option value="04:00">06:00</option>
      </select>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-6" id="timeclosed3">
      <select  name="timeclosed3" class='selectpicker' >
      <option value="00:00">00:00</option>
      <option value="01:00">01:00</option>
      <option value="02:00">02:00</option>
      <option value="03:00">03:00</option>
      <option value="04:00">04:00</option>
      <option value="04:00">05:00</option>
      <option value="04:00">06:00</option>
      </select>
      </div>
        
      <div class="col-sm-6" id="timeopen4">
      <select  name="timeopen4" class='selectpicker' >
      <option value="00:00">00:00</option>
      <option value="01:00">01:00</option>
      <option value="02:00">02:00</option>
      <option value="03:00">03:00</option>
      <option value="04:00">04:00</option>
      <option value="04:00">05:00</option>
      <option value="04:00">06:00</option>
      </select>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-6" id="timeclosed4">
      <select  name="timeclosed4" class='selectpicker' >
      <option value="00:00">00:00</option>
      <option value="01:00">01:00</option>
      <option value="02:00">02:00</option>
      <option value="03:00">03:00</option>
      <option value="04:00">04:00</option>
      <option value="04:00">05:00</option>
      <option value="04:00">06:00</option>
      </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6"><br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="submit_time" >Submit</button>
      </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Sorry, unable to get your need, better if you add your tried js or jQuery piece of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the other answers are missing the point that he values should only be set automatically if the other values have not yet been set.

Add "timeopen" and "timeclosed" classes to your selectors like this:

```
<select name="timeopen1" class='selectpicker timeopen'>
```

Then the following script will change the other three values only if they are still set to "00:00".

```
$(function() {
  $(".timeclosed, .timeopen").change(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("timeopen")) {
      autoSet(".timeopen", this);
    } else {
      autoSet(".timeclosed", this);
    }
  });

  function autoSet(classSelector, t) {
    if ($(classSelector + " option[value='00:00']:selected").length == 3) {
      $(classSelector).val($(t).val());
    }
  }
});
```

This may cause a problem if three of them need to be set to "00:00", as it will then change the fourth one to "00:00" as well.  So instead of checking the values, you may want to use global variables so that the autoSet only runs once for .timeopen and once for .timeclosed.

```
$(function() {
  var autoSetTimeopen = true;
  var autoSetTimeclosed = true;

  $(".timeclosed, .timeopen").change(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("timeopen") && autoSetTimeopen) {
      autoSet(".timeopen", this);
      autoSetTimeopen = false;
    } else if ($(this).hasClass("timeclosed") && autoSetTimeclosed) {
      autoSet(".timeclosed", this);
      autoSetTimeclosed = false;
    }
  });

  function autoSet(classSelector, t) {
    if ($(classSelector + " option[value='00:00']:selected").length == 3) {
      $(classSelector).val($(t).val());
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Many thanks , that is exactly how I expected it to work!

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood you want to display the value you selected in one field in all other fields from the same type. If so you just need to add a class "open" or "closed" to your select inputs and then proceed like this :

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
  var className = 'open';
  if( $(this).hasClass('closed') ) {
    className = 'closed';
  }
  $('select.' + className).val(value);
});
```

Here is your Fiddle updated:
https://jsfiddle.net/az8ujh1e/2/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code which would do what you want, but it is not fully optimized right now. What I would do is, add ids to the select tags, so you can easily work with them with javascript or jquery.

```
$('#timeopen1 select').change(function(){
    var opt = $(this).val()
    for(i = 2; i<=4; i++){
       $('#timeopen'+i.toString()+' select').val(opt);
    }
});
$('#timeclosed1 select').change(function(){
    var opt = $(this).val()
    for(i = 2; i<=4; i++){
       $('#timeclosed'+i.toString()+' select').val(opt);
    }
});
```

EDIT:
Just as someone mentioned in another answer, add classes `timeopen` and `timeclosed` to your `select` elements, so we can easily work with them. Here is the updated code, to set all elements just the first time.

```
$('.selectpicker').one('change',function(event){
    var opt = $(this).val()
      if($(this).hasClass('timeopen'))
    {
        $('.timeopen').each(function(){
        $(this).val(opt);
        $(this).off('change');
      });
    }
        else
    {
        $('.timeclosed').each(function(){
        $(this).val(opt);
        $(this).off('change');
      });
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/az8ujh1e/13/

Comment: Thx, it works already quite good. It is maybe to complicated but what I was imagining is that the first input could be any of the 4 inputs (timeopen1 or 2 or 3 or 4). This implies that the input would only modify once the other selected tags. The first input could then change only if the page has been refreshed.

Comment: This can easily be done, but again the code would be quite complicated, because of the structure of your HTML. Will edit my answer with an example in a bit.

Comment: Thx for your help, I have accepted the answer of @TonyHinkle.